# Delete div after FB.Event.subscribe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

Here my two div.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" id="fb-ONE" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/namePage1" data-width="100" data-height="100" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
<div class="fb-like-box" id="fb-TWO" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/namePage2" data-width="100" data-height="100" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>';
```

Here my code to delete div class fb-like-box.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
     $( ".fb-like-box" ).remove();
  });
};
```

My div have the same class but not the same id. When I subscribe to one I want to delete it. I can not put .fb-like-box because it deletes both even if I didn't like the other. 
Do I have to user Child/Parent ?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried $(this).remove();

Comment: jQuery allows you to use selectors for `class`(.) and `id`(#), e.g., CLASS =  $('.fb-like-box'). ID = $('#fb-ONE'), but if you want to get the exact div that was selected, you can use $(this) or pass some id into the function arguments.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes it doesn't delete nothing

Comment: How to pass the id in the FB.event.subscribe function ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

UPDATED CODE:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(event) {
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {

  });
  $(event.target.id).remove();
};
```

Please tell me if this works.

event.target.id gets the id of the element that called the event.

More Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fb-like-box").click(function(){ 
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

This should work

Comment: When I click I have "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

Comment: Hmm thats strange, how about just linking an .click() func to your div?

Comment: like this for example : $("#fb-0NE").click(function(e) {
    e.remove();
});

Comment: @colinec $(".fb-like-box").click(function(){ $(this).remove(); })

Comment: "object is not a function"

Comment: So, When i like, nothing is happening but I have no error.. I don't understand why.

Comment: @colinec Hmm thats really wierd... I'm sorry but I can't help you anymore I'm out of ideas. Sorry

Comment: Does the order of script like facebook script and my script matter ?

Comment: @colinec Don't know can you try to move your WHOLE fb like button thing to a working js fiddle?

Comment: It still not doing what we want in a js fiddle... It is weird because when I do what there is in my first Question it works. I just want to use the id of it to remove the good one and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @colinec could you share the jsfiddle with me?

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function(event) {
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
     $(event.target.id).remove();
  });
};
```

UPDATED JS :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    if (response == "https://facebook.com/pagename1"){
      $("#fb-TWO").remove();
    }else {
      $("#fb-ONE").remove();
    }
  });
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="fb-like-box" id="fb-ONE" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pageName1" data-width="100" data-height="100" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
<div class="fb-like-box" id="fb-TWO" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pageName2" data-width="100" data-height="100" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```